# custom control with nullable property that has a default value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, user-controls, nullable

I can create a custom control with a default value:

```
private bool exclue = false;
public bool Exclude { get { return exclue; } set { exclue = value; } }
```

I can Create the same thing with a nullable property:

```
private EntityStatuses? status = EntityStatuses.Active;
public EntityStatuses? Status { get { return status; } set { status = value; } }
```

But how can i then set the property to null in markup when using the custom control?

```
<MyControls:Control ID="Con" runat="server" Status="?" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround(with limitation) for nullable property that needs to be set to null in the markup.

Unfortunatelly, `<%= %>` won't work in the case of null value because the string-value of the property on a server-control is evaluated and parsed to its desired type (only simple value, not an expression). But this should work with databinding construction:

```
<MyControls:Control ID="Con" runat="server" Status="<%#(EntityStatuses?)null %>">
```

Now, the problem: using a databinding expression needs to execute a `DataBind()` method either on the control itself or on the entire page. The easiest way is to be sure, your control's `DataBind()` method is called.

So, this is a workaround with limitation only.

Comment: so i understand there is no "proper" way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not set status to null and only change it when it's set in markup?

```
private EntityStatuses? status = null;
public EntityStatuses? Status { get { return status; } set { status = value; } }
```

and

```
<MyControls:Control ID="Con" runat="server" >
```

Comment: I want to have a default value that isn't null. I usually need a certain configuration. i just want to be able to set it to null on the occasions i need it set that way.

Answer (score 0):

Use two properties with different types:

```
<MyControls:Control runat="server" StatusString="Active" />

public string StatusString // string! because all values in markup are strings
{
    set
    {
        EntityStatuses s;
        if (Enum.TryParse(value, out s))
            this.status = s; // local variable
    }
}

public EntityStatuses Status
{
    get { return this.status; }
}
```

or use embedded code block:

```
<MyControls:Control runat="server" Status='<%= EntityStatuses.Active %>' />
```

Comment: Either i don't understand what you wrote, or you didn't understand my meaning.
What in the code above makes the default value be different than null?
What i want is a default value that isn't null and set the ability to set the value to null in markup.

Thanks for the reply

Comment: @user239427: Default value should be set inside the class. Property value can be set out of the class, e.g. from markup. So that's just setting property value, not default property value. Also see my updated post.